# Can't get PS SQL insert to work. Multiple "ExecuteNonQuery" errors

Tags: powershell, command-text

I have below PS that grabs data from AD and puts it in a CSV file. Then it should insert the data to the SQL server and overwrite existing data.

For some reason I just can't get this to work. Spent the last 5 hours searching here and other places but to no avail.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=Nearmiss APP,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=AD" -Recursive | 
Get-ADUser -Properties Mail,displayName | 
Select-Object displayName,Mail | 
Export-CSV -Path D:\autostore\GetADusers\NearMissApp.csv -NoTypeInformation -encoding "unicode" -force
# (Get-Content D:\autostore\GetADusers\NearMissApp-Temp.csv) | % {$_ -replace ‘"‘, ''} | out-file D:\autostore\GetADusers\NearMissApp.csv -Force


#Connect to the SQL database NearMissApp-Users
$sqlsvr = "sql"
$database = "autostore"
$table = "NearMissApp-Users"
$csvFile = "D:\autostore\GetADusers\NearMissApp.csv"


#Create SQL Connection
$cmd.Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$sqlsvr;Initial Catalog=$database; Integrated Security=true")
$cmd.command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$cmd.Connection.Open()

Import-Csv $csvFile -Header displayName,Mail | % {
  $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO $table (displayName, Mail) VALUES ('$($_.displayName)', '$($_.Mail)')"   | Out-host
  $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  }

  $cmd.connection.close
```

The error I get is:

Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "ExecuteNonQuery: CommandText property has not been initialized"
At D:\autostore\GetADusers\GetUsers-NearMiss-App-DBupdate.ps1:23 char:3
+   $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

Comment: First thing I'd try is to write the SQL command text to a file or the screen so you can check that you have valid SQL.

Comment: How $cmd is defined?

Comment: It looks like either $cmd.command or $cmd.CommandText is a wrong notation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `| Out-host` from  `$cmd.CommandText = ...` line.